# How to use SSL with Vue CLI for local development?

Tags: ssl, vue.js, vue-cli

I understand to use https with Vue CLI I can set "https: true" under devServer in a vue.config.js file, but I also need a self signed certificate.

I've tried generating a self signed one using OpenSSL and using the following in my vue.config.js file to target:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: '8081',
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.cert'),
        },
    },
};
```

Chrome confirms it's using my certificate but still shows https as "Not secure"

[image]

***How can I make chrome assess my self signed certificate as secure when providing it via Vue CLI?***

Comment: Are you trying to use a cert with the subject name of 'localhost'? Cuz...........that'll have to be self signed. If you want to use a public cert to protect your site, you need to get a cert for "vue-gui.mydomain.com" (or whatever the URL is), a wildcard cert would also work... but in no way would a public cert provider give you a cert for 'localhost'..

Comment: For what URL are you trying to generate a cert for? Do you have a local cert authority? [Please see this link for more info](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) - typically generating a cert for 'localhost' is not a good thing..

Comment: [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) makes it this trivial. It will generate a root CA and install the cert into the trusted stores for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I installed mkcert and it's working!

Comment: if on Chrome see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31900210/3660269

Answer (score 8):

Simply enter this in your Chrome

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

Set to `Enabled`, restart Chrome, and you're good to go.

Comment: Not if you are using a virtual host.

Answer (score 6):

My problem was that everybody talks about putting the cert properties in the "https" child configuration node, but this doesn't work, you hve to put it in the devServer config node:

```
module.exports = {
devServer: {
    port: '8081',
    https: {
       key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.key'),
          --> this is WRONG
```

This is the correct way:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    port:8080,
    host: 'xxxxxx',
    https: true,
    //key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/xxxxxx.pem'),
    //cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/xxxxxx.pem'),
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('./certs/xxxxxx.pfx'),
    pfxPassphrase: "xxxxxx",
    public: 'https://xxxxxx:9000/',
    https: true,
    hotOnly: false,
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is interesting. Official documentation for Webpack.JS states otherwise; but this solution works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the network path rather than loopback or localhost. For example

`https://192.168.2.210:8080/`

works fine, while

`https://localhost:8080/` and `https://127.0.0.1:8080` balk at the certificate problem.

Comment: This simply works, thanks
I also needed to change my Java API address (.env.dev) to 127.0.0.1:8081 to stop the HTTP 307 redirection to HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right, but you also have to add the self-signed cert inside certification authorities of your browser, as it is self-signed.

Instead of using a self-signed certificate, you can also create a root certificate, and then generate a *localhost* or other server identifier certificate. I recommend this solution because this way you can generate certificates for all **non production environments** and import only one custom certification authority.

There are many sites where you can find how to do it, one of them I think it's very clear is [How to create an HTTPS certificate for localhost domains](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/9492b848eb8fe46d462abeb26656c4f8#how-to-create-an-https-certificate-for-localhost-domains). Basically you have to follow these steps described in that link:

1. Generate certification authority key:

   openssl req -x509 -nodes -new -sha256 -days 1024 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout RootCA.key -out RootCA.pem -subj "/C=US/CN=Example-Root-CA"

Here we have to change the parameters as we wish, mainly *-sub* parameter.

2. Generate certificate for certification authority

   openssl x509 -outform pem -in RootCA.pem -out RootCA.crt
3. Generate key for *localhost*

   openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=YourState/L=YourCity/O=Example-Certificates/CN=localhost.local"

Where you have to change *-subj* as you need or leave it that way.

4. Generate localhost certificate by creating a certificate config file and request openssl to generate it.

This is the certificate config file:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = fake1.local
DNS.3 = fake2.local
```

And this is the command to generate the certificate:

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 1024 -in localhost.csr -CA RootCA.pem -CAkey RootCA.key -CAcreateserial -extfile domains.ext -out localhost.crt
```

Once you have the certificate, you have to import the certification authority on your preferred browser. You can, also, follow 3 and 4 steps for every server or virtual machine you need for development and use them without needing to import new certification authorities in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you have legit certificates Chad Carter gives a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57226788/2363056

The steps are as follows:

1. create `vue.config.js` in your projects root (if not there already)
2. add the following code to it:

```
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
    port:8080,
    host: 'example.com',
    https: true,
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/keys/example.com.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/keys/example.com/cert.pem'),
    https: true,
    hotOnly: false,
    }
}
```

3. when serving your project, ensure https is enabled (ie. `$ vue-cli-service serve --https true`)

Answer (score 0):

I use the mkcert to create trusted https cert on windows OS.
[mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert).
[image: the local config]

[image: the bat cmd content]

Last thing you should do is openning your OS explorer, click the `install.bat` file

Answer (score 0):

After going through the compiler errors, this is what worked for me:

`vue.config.js`

```
devServer: {
    server: {
      type: 'https',
      options: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key/file'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert/file'),
        passphrase: 'pass_phrase_if_applicable'
      }
    }
  }
```

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --https"
}
```