# How to run Vue-cli project using https on Windows

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ssl-certificate

I am trying to run a vue-cli project using https.

As per the instructions here [How to run Vue.js dev serve with https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807049/how-to-run-vue-js-dev-serve-with-https)

I've added the `https` setting to the `vue.config.js` as per below:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      https: true
    }
}
```

When I run the app it correctly runs as https://localhost:8080 however Chrome throws an `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error.

It appears I need to setup an SSL certificate in Windows and set some configuration in `vue.config.js`. Does anyone know how to do this?  Note, this question applies specifically to Windows.

Comment: Under the hood Vue-cli is just using `webpack-dev-server`, so it's less to do with `vue` and more to do with the aforementioned.

Webpack has actually provided a full guide and walkthrough to creating an https driven local environment on Windows. You can [find the guide here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/examples/cli/https)

Comment: Your localhost self-signed certificate (generated by vue-cli) is not trusted by your computer/browser. Have you checked this famous question already in order to trust it ? --https://stackoverflow.com/q/7580508/2474214

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The Link to the guide is broken.

Comment: @Marcel https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/examples/https/object

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was building multiple applications that were sometimes sharing the same port. I fixed it by switching to a different port:

```
module.exports = {
   devServer: {
     port: 8081
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code that is working for me

`module.exports = { devServer: {server: {type: "https",},client:{webSocketURL:"auto://localhost:8080/ws",},allowedHosts: "all",},}`

Don't forget to change the port number if you use another port

This way working on vuejs 2.7v