# VuePress: How can I use https in dev server?

Tags: https, vuepress

Is there any hook to enable https in VuePress dev server?

#### 1. Current solution.

I directly add one line to `node_modules/@vuepress/core/lib/node/dev/index.js`. This works well, but nasty.

```
  createServer () {
    const contentBase = path.resolve(this.context.sourceDir, '.vuepress/public')

    const serverConfig = Object.assign({

      https: true, // <--- Added this line.

      disableHostCheck: true,
      compress: true,
      clientLogLevel: 'error',
```

- [vuejs/vuepress - /packages/@vuepress/core/lib/node/dev/index.js#L197-L237](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/7e9d0c1f42196dee52daabfaf796e0cdaa7bd6eb/packages/%40vuepress/core/lib/node/dev/index.js#L197-L237)

#### 2. Background

Because Chrome has changed it's security policy, CORS.

[image: Image: "Mark cross-site cookies as Secure to allow them to be sent in cross-site requests."]

#### 3. What I've tried.

- **I've tried but not working.**

  - [webpack - devServer.https](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttps)

`docs/.vuepress/config.js`

```
  configureWebpack: (config, isServer) => {
    if (!config.devServer) {
      config.devServer = {}
    }
    Object.assign(config.devServer, {
      https: true,
    })
  }
```

- **No proper hook**

  - [VuePress - Plugin Option API - beforeDevServer](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/option-api.html#beforedevserver)
  - [VuePress - Plugin Option API - afterDevServer](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/option-api.html#afterdevserver)
- **No command option for https**.

  - [vuejs/vuepress - /packages/vuepress/lib/registerCoreCommands.js#L18-L31](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/15784acc0cf2e87de3c147895b2c3977b0195d78/packages/vuepress/lib/registerCoreCommands.js#L18-L31)

```
module.exports = function (cli, options) {
  cli
    .command(`dev [targetDir]`, 'start development server')
    .option('-p, --port <port>', 'use specified port (default: 8080)')
    .option('-t, --temp <temp>', 'set the directory of the temporary file')
    .option('-c, --cache [cache]', 'set the directory of cache')
    .option('--host <host>', 'use specified host (default: 0.0.0.0)')
    .option('--no-cache', 'clean the cache before build')
    .option('--no-clear-screen', 'do not clear screen when dev server is ready')
    .option('--debug', 'start development server in debug mode')
    .option('--silent', 'start development server in silent mode')
    .option('--open', 'open browser when ready')
    .action((sourceDir = '.', commandOptions) => {
      const { debug, silent } = commandOptions
```

#### 4. Related links.

- [vuejs/vuepress - Support devServer.proxy in configureWebpack #858](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/858)
- [vuejs/vuepress - Sunsetting webpack-serve #1195](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/pull/1195)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community! Seems you have tried to format question yourself, it's.. well at least you tried. Just read this article (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) it will help you in future to handle Markdown. And don't forget to upvote users which provide useful information on your question and mark it as solved.

Comment: Copy that, sir :)

Comment: Check this question, will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807049/how-to-run-vue-js-dev-serve-with-https

Comment: Gabriel Willemann, thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following settings to `config.js`.

```js
//
// docs/.vuepress/config.js
//
module.exports = {

  devServer: {
    https: true
  },

}
```

- [How to run Vue.js dev serve with https? - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807049/how-to-run-vue-js-dev-serve-with-https)

Thank you for your guidance in many ways.